# define a map over boolean scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, boolean

I am trying to change the value of an array based on the value of a different array. In particular these are the arrays I am working with:

```
val inpoly: Array[Boolean]=Array(false, true, true, false)
val idx1: Array[Boolean]=Array(true, false, false, false)
```

I would like to check the array idx1 and where it is true I would like to assign to a new vector the opposite value of the array inpoly in that specific position, otherwise, just leave the value that inpoly already has.

My expectation would be to have this array:

```
final_vector= true, true, true, false
```

since the first value of idx1 is true, change the first value of inpoly. All the other values of idx1 are false, so leave the inpoly as it is

I tried with the following code:

```
idx1.map({
case true => !inpoly
case false => inpoly}
)
```

However i get the following error:

```
<console>:73: error: value unary_! is not a member of Array[Boolean]
              case true => !inpoly
                           ^
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040243/update-an-array-based-on-its-values-and-the-values-of-another-array for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an element-by-element comparison of two collections. The best way to do this is to `zip` them together and then `map` the two values to give the answer:

```
inpoly.zip(idx1).map{ case (poly, idx) => poly ^ idx }
```

In this case the two values are xor-ed, but clearly you can use any combination of the two values to generate the result.

Comment: Thank you, what instead I would like to assign true, every time I have true in another vector, and leave as it is when is false?

Comment: `poly || idx` should do that. If `poly` is `true` it is `true`, otherwise it is whatever value `idx` has.