# Update an Array based on its values and the values of another Array

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, boolean

I am trying to change the value of an array based on the value of a different array. In particular these are the arrays I am working with:

```
val inpoly: Array[Boolean]=Array(false, true, true, false)
val idx1: Array[Boolean]=Array(true, false, false, false)
```

I would like to check the array `idx1` and where it is true I would like to set `inpoly` to true in that specific position, otherwise, just leave the value that `inpoly` already has.

My expected result would be to have this array:

```
final_vector= true, true, true, false
```

since the first value of `idx1` is true, assign true to `inpoly`. All the other values of `idx1` are false, so leave `inpoly` as it is

I tried the following code:

```
idx1.map({
  case true => true
  case false => inpoly})
```

However I get the following result:

```
res308: Array[Any] = Array(true, Array(false, true, true, false), Array(false, true, true, false), Array(false, true, true, false))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'd like to use an "OR" on the pairs of booleans. Here's one approach using `||` which is Scala's OR function:

```
val updated = inpoly.zip(idx1).map(pair => pair._1 || pair._2)
```

which would give you:

```
updated: Array[Boolean] = Array(true, true, true, false)
```

Here, zip will combine the two arrays into one array of pairs. Then you will map through those pairs and return a true if either are true and a false if both are false.

You could also use a pattern match:

```
val updated = inpoly.zip(idx1).map {
 case (left, right) => left || right
 case _ => None 
}
```

You'll want to think about what you will do in the case that one Array has a different length than the other.

And, if you insist on modifying `inpoly` rather than creating a new array, do the following:

```
var inpoly: Array[Boolean]=Array(false, true, true, false)
val idx1: Array[Boolean]=Array(true, false, false, false)

inpoly = inpoly.zip(idx1).map(pair => pair._1 || pair._2)
```

Note that here, we declare `inpoly` to be a `var`, not a `val`. However, I would instead suggest keeping `inpoly` as a `val` and creating a new `val` for the updated version of that array. Using immutable values is a recommended practice in Scala, though it can take some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip both arrays, so you can iterate over pair of values fe.:

```
idx1.zip(inpoly).map{
  case (true, _) => true
  case (_, value) => value
}
```

But be aware that this code will create new array, `inpoly` won't be changed.